# ie8 print to pdf with css filter on body for strech background image

Tags: css, pdf, internet-explorer-8

My stylesheet contains the folowing rows, for strech backgound image in ie8 and earlier,
its works perfectly, but when I try printing to pdf file its sticks the computer:

```
body
{
height:100%;
width:100% ;
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader( src="/images/LOGO.PNG", sizingMethod="scale");
}
```

How can I do it well?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Media queries are your friend, :-)

```
@media screen {
    body {
        filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader( src="/images/LOGO.PNG", sizingMethod="scale");
    }
}
@media print {
    body {
        background-image: url("/images/LOGO.PNG");
    }
}
```

That will force browsers to only apply your filter in screen, so it won't land on printing (to pdf or otherwise).

Here's more info about media queries in [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries)'s website.

Comment: I want the logo will appear in print too.